# Show that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n log(i)$ is O(n log n)

Tags: algorithms, summation, asymptotics

How can I show that $\sum \limits_{i=1}^n \log(i)$ is $O(n \log n)?$ (Log in base 2).

Answer (score 3):

$$\log(1) + \log(2) + \dots + \log(n)$$

is bounded above by

$$\overbrace{\log(n) + \log(n) + \dots + \log(n)}^{n\text{ terms}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can use the [Abel summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_summation_formula) to get $$\sum_{i\leq n}\log\left(i\right)=n\log\left(n\right)-\int_{1}^{n}\frac{\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor }{t}dt
 $$ where $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor 
 $ is the floor function. Then, using the fact that $\left\lfloor t\right\rfloor =t+O\left(1\right)
 $ we have $$\sum_{i\leq n}\log\left(i\right)=n\log\left(n\right)-n+O\left(\log\left(n\right)\right).
 $$ then your claim follows.